# How can I add datetime column to np.array

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to know. How can I add datetime column to np.array. I wrote this code. But it dosn't work and I get a exception 'Cannot convert from specific units to generic units in NumPy datetimes or timedeltas'

```
trade_type = np.dtype(
    [
        ('id', 'U'),
        ('timestamp', 'u8'),
        ('datetime', np.dtype('datetime64'))
    ]
)

array = np.zeros(shape=1, dtype=trade_type)
array['datetime'] = np.datetime64('1970-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will work if you specify a time unit parameter as **dtype='datetime64[s]'** on your array creation.

here is the working code:

```
trade_type = np.dtype(
[
    ('id', 'U'),
    ('timestamp', 'u8'),
    ('datetime', np.dtype('datetime64[s]'))
]
)

array = np.zeros(shape=1, dtype=trade_type)
array['datetime'] = np.datetime64('1970-01-01 00:00:00')
```

output:

[image]

[image]

*hope i did understand right.*

reference: [Datetimes and Timedeltas](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html)